# How to get constant String from switch statement in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to set the hint- and labeltext of a `TextFormField` to a string from the `getLabel()` method, depending on which `FormFieldType` is given as parameter in `generateFormField()`.
However, the hint- and labeltext require a constant value. `getLabel()` throws this error: `Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant)`

How can I get a constant string from the switch statement?

```dart
class InformationFormField {

  TextFormField generateFormField(FormFieldType type) {
     return new TextFormField(
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
        hintText: getLabel(type),         // This requires a constant String
        labelText: getLabel(type),        // This requires a constant String
      ),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
     );
  }

  String getLabel(FormFieldType type) {
    switch(type) {
      case FormFieldType.firstname:
        return 'First name';
      case FormFieldType.lastname:
        return 'Last name';
  }

}

enum FormFieldType {
  firstname,
  lastname
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Simply remove the `const` qualifier where you construct the `InputDecoration`.

---

In Dart, `const` means a *compile-time* constant, a value that is known at compilation time and used as a performance optimization.

Since you're calling a function (and passing along an non-`const` argument, no less), the return value of that function cannot be known at compilation time.

You don't actually need to use constant values.  The lines you've marked with `// This requires a constant String` require a constant only because you declared that you intend to construct a `const InputDecoration`. (Constructing a compile-time constant naturally requires that all of its construction arguments also be compile-time constants.)